# How to read single column multiple rows csv file as an array using php

Tags: php, csv

I have requirement where my csv file has urls,which i need to read as an array.The  csv file has single column having mutiple rows with no header.I am reading using the below code.But it was not returning the output what i needed.

```
$handle = fopen($this->local_temp_folder.$file, 'r');
        if(!$handle)
        {
            Model_Log::error('Cannot open uploaded file.');
            die('Cannot open uploaded file.');
        }

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE)
    {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $url_array[$c] = $data[$c];
    }
    } 


print_r($url_array);exit;
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.test.com/Fo/Finder/Digital_C/
http://www.test.com/Fo/Finder/orders/HighD/R56/
)
But i want it like the array as follows
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.test.com/Fo/Finder/Digital_C/
    [1] => http://www.test.com/Fo/Finder/orders/HighD/R56/
)
```

I have checked the csv file with note pad.In notepad it was looking like this
http://www.test.com/Fo/Finder/Digital_C/http://www.test.com/Fo/Finder/orders/HighD/R56/
But when i open with excel it was showing in two rows.

Comment: you solved the issue ? i have a code

Comment: no it was not solved,Can you please post so that i will check with that

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle = fopen($this->local_temp_folder.$file, 'r');
if(!$handle)
{
   Model_Log::error('Cannot open uploaded file.');
   die('Cannot open uploaded file.');
}

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE)
{
    $url_array[] = $data[0];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code but it showing only one row.This is the output when i tried above.Array
(
    [0] => http://www.test.com/Fo/Finder/Digital_C/
)

Comment: Hi Thanks,your code solved my problem.Previously there is a problem with my csv file now ok.

Answer (score 0):

try this, but if you share your csv file it would better to help you.

```
function read($file){
    $data = array();
    $csv_file = $file['folder'] . $file['name'];
    $csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
    if(!feof($csvfile)){
        $i = 0;
        while (!feof($csvfile)) {
            $csv_data[] = fgetcsv($csvfile, 1000, ",");
            $data[] = array(
                'column1' => !empty($csv_data[$i][0])?$csv_data[$i][0]:'empty',
                'column2' => !empty($csv_data[$i][1])?$csv_data[$i][1]:'empty',
                'column3' => !empty($csv_data[$i][2])?$csv_data[$i][2]:'empty',
                'column4' => !empty($csv_data[$i][3])?$csv_data[$i][3]:'empty',
                'column5' => !empty($csv_data[$i][4])?$csv_data[$i][4]:'empty'
            );
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
$data = read(array('folder'=>'','name'=>'file.csv'));//same folder
var_dump($data);
```